# Automatically align the children of div to bottom in vertical direction and left in horizontal direction when the div is resized

Tags: css

I am trying to arrange the children elements of a div to bottom of it automatically,when the div is resized . here is my html . please help me . thanks.

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;vertical-align:bottom;">
    <a>more...</a>
    <input type="button"  value="query" />
</div>​
```

Comment: That is not `code` that is `markup`. What have you tried so far? This cannot be all.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't stated it clearly. I want to use `css` not using `code`. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPTION 1 :You can add a css class to both the child elements and give a position attribute.
Something like this

```
<a class = "myclass">more...</a>
<input class = "myclass" type="button"  value="query" />
```

And then you can style your css like this

```
.myclass{position:relative;top:90%;}​​​​​
```

OPTION2: You can put both the child elements in a sub div block and add the css class to that div. Something like this

```
<div class = "myclass">
    <a >more...</a>
    <input type="button"  value="query" />
</div>
```

With the same CSS style
Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank for your answer , I found `vertical-align` doesn't work in `div` , but it is work in `table`. I think sometime it is better to use `table` instead `div` .